# How do i redirect a domain while displaying the old address?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, domain-name

I've generated a .htaccess file using the host service to 301 permanent redirect from an empty subdomain to the new subdomain page in a folder.

`sejur-avion.old-domain.com` --> `subdomain.new-domain.com/agent/5049/sejur-avion`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sejur\-avion\.old\-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sejur\-avion\.old\-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.new\-domain\.com\/agent\/5049\/sejur\-avion\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

What i need to do is hide the "new-domain" name from the address bar, and if possible display the old domain's name instead.

So what i need is for `subdomain.new-domain.com/agent/5049/sejur-avion` to display as `subdomain.old-domain.com/agent/5049/sejur-avion`

I've heard there's a ServerAlias function that i can use for that?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod rewrite's `P` flag which sends the request to be reverse proxied via mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sejur\-avion\.old\-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sejur\-avion\.old\-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.new\-domain\.com\/agent\/5049\/sejur\-avion\/$1" [P,L]
```

(Essentially replacing the `R=301` with a `P`)

This, however, requires that you have mod_proxy loaded, which isn't always the case. If that module isn't loaded, you're unlikely get an error (just nothing happens).

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work. where can i load mod_proxy please?
i'm using hostgator.